# What does 0 flag mean in shmflg for shared V memory system calls?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

```
   int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);
```

The above function is given as per man shmget. The flags available for the third parameters are given in the man and are well defined. But time to time I see people using 0 passed to the flag. What does the 0 mean? I can't find anywhere online the meaning of 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of `shmflg` is as follows:

```
                  11     10           9     8           0 : bits
---------------------------------------------------------
| additional flags  | IPC_EXCL | IPC_CREAT | mode flags |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

The mode flags are interpreted in the same ways as the `flags` parameter of the `open` system call. A value of zero for the mode flags means `O_RDONLY`.

The values of bits 9 and 10 are to be interpreted as follows:

- 00 : Use the existing segment associated with the key. If it does not exist, return the error `ENOENT`.
- 01 : Create a new segment if the segment associated with the key does not exist. Otherwise, use the existing segment.
- 10 : *I think* this is treated the same as 00 (can someone confirm?).
- 11 : Create a new segment if the segment associated with the key does not exist. Otherwise, return the error `EEXIST`.

Of course, an existing segment can only be accessed if the current user has the required permissions.

A value of zero for the additional flags means a normal segment (no `SHM_HUGETLB` or other such flags).

Comment: I believe IPC_EXCL is ignored if IPC_CREAT is not set, so your "10 same as 00" is correct.  See POSIX [`shmget()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html) and [`<sys/ipc.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_ipc.h.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The problem is that the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) only says  that an error occurs when "no segment exists for the given key, and IPC_CREAT was not specified." But it does not say what happens when the segment does exist and only `IPC_EXCL` was specified. Not sure even whether the behavior is the same on different Linux kernels. Also specifying `IPC_EXCL` only does not make much sense, so maybe there is some kernel out there that considers that case an error.

Comment: Well, I've certainly not checked every implementation, but the IPC_EXCL flag is irrelevant – and hence ignorable — unless IPC_CREAT is also specified.  It is improbable that a kernel generates an error for IPC_EXCL and no IPC_CREAT; there is no specified error to generate, though I suppose the ubiquitous EINVAL would be generated.

Comment: what does it mean by normal segment? In the context used by the textbook, I'm gathering that it is already asking to get ID of the shared memory created by another process. Could you please explain further?

Comment: @YashJain If you refer to the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget), you'll see that there are some additional flags such as `SHM_HUGETLB` and `SHM_NORESERVE`. A value of zero means these flags are not used. If you're reading from a textbook, you can just ignore these flags until the book explicitly mentions them.